# Vue3 + Vite Error HMR while editing typescript file

Tags: vuejs3, vite, hmr

I have an issue on my vue app, I enabled the HRM in my application, it's working properly for vue file but when i'm editing a typescript file I have this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')`
I'm using these version for vue and vite

```
"vitest": "^0.33.0",
"vue": "^3.2.47",
```

My vite config

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
  return {
    base: "./",
    plugins: [
      vue(),
    ],
    server: {
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
      }
    },
}
});
```

Do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: It would be prudent to include the relevant code that is producing the error in your question.

Comment: I found the bug but I don't know how to solve it, it's happens when I try to init Sentry on my main.ts